# Adding Fields to Entity for Data Import and Power Query Analysis without Touching Dynamics Solutions

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerquery, cds, power-platform

I came into one of those situations that are always used as an opposite of ideal example in tutorials. Custom built CRM, and no access to the firm who built it. For that reason, for the moment, we are not touching solutions because I lack the documentation to make safe decisions on major changes to the Dynamics end of things.

That said, I use power query to analyze the data on a daily basis. For some of our needs, could I theoretically, add fields to the entities, then data import to those fields, and analyze through power query?

Does this route temporarily usurp the potential of messing up the prod environment while giving us the ability to track new data points, add them (without creating a new form to fill out) and access the data for tracking and analysis?

Am I missing any glaring relationship issues between Dynamics and CDS or does this keep the changes on the CDS side? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your thrid party solution is managed?
However if you wish to create field in prod let’s say for account entity.

Crete new unmanaged solution, add account entity without any component(empty, just account) then create new fields, as per your requirement do not add them to any form or views.

Once you publish this fields are available for your use.

After all the analysis if you wish to delete those fields, go to your newly create solution and delete the fields (delete and not just remove)

This shall help and will not cause any issue.

Comment: Some are managed and some aren't. I'm concerned about making changes that aren't in the rest of the development instances when we rollup in the future or try to promote solutions properly that don't contain the prod changes. I have the credentials to add fields directly through the powerplatform/cds portal. My thought was that I might not create any solution at all.

Comment: If you do not need those fields in future you can delete them directly in your prod system. Solution because you have container to know what you created or updated.

Comment: I want the fields permanently as part of the entity- I just don't want to disrupt any future development processes. If I add it outside of the solutions, directly under the data tab, and then data upload to those points, do you think it would cause any issue to Dynamics?